# Eclipse, ColdFusion Builder, Debug in built-in browser

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, coldfusionbuilder

I've been using Eclipse Classic with the ColdFusion Builder 2 Plug-ins and I was wondering if there was a way to launch the debugger in a browser within Eclipse. I've seen a browser in Eclipse before, but I'm not sure where it's hiding... and if it's possible to launch the debugger within it instead of the external browser.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Eclipse classic the only way to open the Internal Web Browser are the following.

Open the Internal web browser view:

1. Window > Show View > General > Internal Web Browser

Or you can do this:

1. Create  .html file
2. Right-click the file and choose open-with > Web Browser

The easiest thing to do would be to install the Webtools feature from the webtools update-site and then add the "Web Browser" action set to the perspective.

1. Right click toolbar and choose "customize perspective"
2. Go to command group availability
3. Enable "Web Browser"

This will add a "open web browser" action on the toolbar.